# Why does Vitest sometimes not rerun tests while in watch mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vitest

I am new to Vitest and struggling hard to get up to speed on it.

I am using the current version of VSCode as my IDE and have Vitest V0.23.4 installed. (I included it in the project from the very beginning.) I know that `npm run test:unit` is supposed to put Vitest in watch mode so that every time I save my files, my test suites run automatically. That only seems to work about half the time. I have autoSave with delay set in my VSCode settings so that it saves automatically after 1000 milliseconds but, despite that, and even when I do a save manually, there only seems to be roughly a 50/50 chance of the tests starting by themselves. Quite often, I have to type `q` to quit and restart the tests. Other times, the tests *do* run automatically like they're supposed to.

Does anyone know why this is misbehaving so inconsistently? I'd like it to work as designed instead of in this hit-or-miss fashion.